# how to notify webserver when user closes the browser (in asp.net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am developing a relay chat application , divided into 2 panes.

right pane - > The Chat responses of users (this uses a ASP.NET Multiline Label control placed inside the update panel , so when any user types the responses and submits it is added to this control)

left panes -> the list of users currently online(this uses ASP.NET list control which is also placed inside the update panel).

below this is the textbox for the user to enter text and a send button to post his response.

everything works fine. But when user closes the browser window instead of clicking the log out button. the list on the left pane is not getting refreshed.

It happens properly , when the user logs out.

IS there any way to knock of the users name from the list if the user closes  the browser?(even before his session is expired on the server side).?

sorry i couldn expose the screen shot.

can any one suggest an idea along with a sample code snippet.?

thanks

[vijay](http://apvijay.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the other way around: ping the server from the browser with an ajax call periodically. If no ping received, remove the user.

Comment: I tried that . seems we are polling and that drinks up the effieciency.

Comment: I think this is the only reliable way. You can make it more efficient if you only ping if the user did not send any messages for a given time. Also for idle users you can dynamically increase the timeout interval after each ping.

Answer (score 2):

You can [use Javascript to detect when the browser has been closed](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=93810), and then kick-off an AJAX request back to the server notifying that the user left.

Comment: @bcwood.  It fires off everytime a user moves to another page.  I don't think they will be able to reliably use this to detect the user is closing the browser from the reading from this forum.  Did I miss something?

Comment: @klabranche but if they navigate away from the current page, the have left the chat application, which might as well be the same as closing their browser.